# String format truncating value

Tags: string, go, printf

This is going to be a simple question to answer, I am sure of it. I am brand new to Go and I can't figure out what is happening.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("*A basic GoLang/Native example*\n\n")
    fmt.Print("Enter your name:\n")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    name, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")

    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s, how are you?", name)

    reader.ReadString('\n')

}
```

I am removing the newline which is stored in variable name from reading in the user input, but the last Printf statement is truncating Hello, from the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `strings.TrimSpace`.

To remove the leading and trailing white spaces use [this](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace).

Change this line from

`name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")`

to

`name = strings.TrimSpace(name)`

> Output:
>
> ```
> *A basic GoLang/Native example*
>
> Enter your name:
> Source Cast
> Hello, Source Cast, how are you?
> ```

It is working fine for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: geez thanks, there is a book that states to remove newlines entered from user input, to use strings.TrimSuffix. I suppose that is not correct... Here is a link if you are curious. https://flaviocopes.com/golang-remove-new-line-from-readstring/

Comment: Unfortunately it is correct for Linux but not for windows.